# bibunits and natbib

Tags: natbib, subdividing, bibunits

I a writing a report which contains serveral section each of them should have their own references. This task should be done with natbib. Unfortunately `natbib` and `binunits` seem not go together very well and it just does't create any references. If I use

```
\defaultbibliographystyle{alphadin}
```

instead of

```
\bibliographystyle*{plainnat}
```

however, it seems to work. Here is a snippet of my LaTeX file:

```
\begin{bibunit}
some text

\nocite{*}
\putbib[bib]

\end{bibunit}


\RequirePackage{bibunits}
\RequirePackage[sort&compress]{natbib}
\RequirePackage{natbib}

\bibliographyunit[\section]
\bibliographystyle*{plainnat}
\bibliographyunit

\begin{bibunit}
some tex
\nocite{*}
\putbib[bib]
\end{bibunit}
```