# natbib and bibunits do not seem to work together

Tags: bibtex, natbib, bibunits

I am struggling to get `bibunits` and `natbib` to work together, even though bibunits claims to be compatible with natbib.

(To give some context, in the end, I wish to produce chapter bibliographies, where each chapter has a separate `.bib`-file.)

The problem is that either I place `\usepackage{natbib}` before  `\usepackage{bibunits}` in which case compilation works, but any options (e.g. authoryear) from natbib are completely ignored.

Is there something I need to do/add to make bibunits use author-year style as I wish?

While the above order seems natural and at least produces a complete document, I also tried the reverse:
If I reverse the order (bibunits before natbib), compilation fails (both in overleaf and texstudio). More precisely, it seems on the first run (after processing bu1.aux) it produces a pdf with ? in the text in place of the citations, and subsequent runs either go on without ever terminating and without an error message, or they just produce the error `Package natbib Error: Bibliography not compatible with author-year citations. ...mmand\NAT@force@numbers{}\NAT@force@numbers`
The latter error appears even when not using the authoryear option of natbib.

Example is below, or use this overleaf link:
https://www.overleaf.com/read/spdfhstxqrtr

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[round,authoryear]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{ecta}
\usepackage{bibunits}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
    @ARTICLE{Meyer2000,
        AUTHOR="Bernd Meyer",
        TITLE="A constraint-based framework for diagrammatic reasoning",
        JOURNAL="Applied Artificial Intelligence",
        VOLUME= "14",
        ISSUE = "4",
        PAGES= "327--344",
        YEAR=2000
    }
    @ARTICLE{Codishetal2000,
        AUTHOR="M. Codish and K. Marriott and C.K. Taboch",
        TITLE="Improving program analyses by structure untupling",
        JOURNAL="Journal of Logic Programming",
        VOLUME= "43",
        ISSUE = "3",
        PAGES= "251--263",
        YEAR=2000
    }
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
    \begin{bibunit}
        References to the \TeX book \cite{Meyer2000}
        and to Lamport’s \LaTeX\ book, which appears
        only in the references \citep{Codishetal2000}.
        \putbib[mybib]
    \end{bibunit}
\end{document}
```

I do realize this question: [bibunits and natbib](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/148660/bibunits-and-natbib) is related, but it does not seem to be the same (I can't get it to work regardless of styles etc.), also the question is incomplete, without working example etc., so I hope it is ok to ask what I am asking.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I seemed to have overlooked the obvious:

`\begin{bibunit}[ecta]`

(or whichever style is desired) does the trick (but it needs to go after
`usepackage{bibunits}` of course).